# Converting alphanumeric string into long using parseLong

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to take a string I generate and convert it into a long using the following:

```
 Long id1L = Long.parseLong(makeID(tumor_type, featureType1, name1), 36)
 Long id2L = Long.parseLong(makeID(tumor_type, featureType2, name2), 36)
 long id1 = id1L.longValue()
 long id2 = id2L.longValue()
```

Where makeID returns a lowercase, alphanumeric string. I thought that passing 36 as the radix would convert the letters, but I'm getting a NumerFormatException that outputs the original string when I try to pass id1 or id2 into a function requiring a long value. Am I misunderstanding how parseLong() works? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you add an assertion that demonstrates successful conversion. Like this for example: `assert Long.parseLong('abc123', 36) == 456`?

Comment: plase also provide the result (type and value) of makeID with your example

Comment: Make sure the number you want to convert to Long is less than Long.MAX_VALUE (9223372036854775807) as using 36 radix can easily produce very large numbers. This is the maximum Long you can get using the letter `z`: `Long.parseLong('zzzzzzzzzzzz', 36)`.

Comment: Make also sure that the string produced by makeID() contains only alphanumeric characters (0-9, A-Z or a-z). Lowercase and uppercase characters will be mapped to the same number (b_36 = B_36 = 11_10).

Comment: "...but I'm getting a NumerFormatException that outputs the original string when I try to pass id1 or id2 into a function requiring a long value" - That does not make sense.  Are you sure that the exception is the result of passing id1 or id2 value to a function?  It makes more sense that the exception would come from the `parseLong` or your `makeID` method.

Comment: Thanks @defectus, I hadn't considered that. That was the issue. I found another way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the problem here was the input data.

> Make sure the number you want to convert to Long is less than `Long.MAX_VALUE` (9223372036854775807) as using 36 radix can easily produce very large numbers. This is the maximum Long you can get using the letter z: `Long.parseLong('zzzzzzzzzzzz', 36)`

An option around is to use a `BigInteger`:

```
groovy:000> new BigInteger('z'*42, 36)
===> 231582123678838102672736490567111386503858361810075859110326173695
```